# Django: Avoid rendering as variable in template

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

I just started learning django for a few day. Django's  templating system looks fascinating. but currently I am facing an issue.
I need to print this kind of text in my webpage multiple times through template.

```
She {{ was }} a very  {{ helpful }} and {{ attractive}} girl.
```

But whenever I try to use this in template, it thinks those words are variable thaI am referring, and vanishes them from the output due to not getting a value. So the output becomes,

```
She a very and girl.
```

I completely understand that this is the intended behaviour, but in some case I am trying to tell the rendering engine to render that as it is. Is there any filter or workaround??
[ I have to use them inside the template, and they can't be passed through variables as string]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the verbatim template tag, which will stop rendering what is inside the tag. See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim).

```
{% verbatim %}
    She {{ was }} a very  {{ helpful }} and {{ attractive}} girl.
{% endverbatim %}
```